# Efficient algorithm to check if a value is in a list of list and retreive the index of the element

Tags: python, list, algorithm

My goal is to **efficiently** find in a large list of list (let's take as an example 1 mln of entries and each entry is a list composed of 3 elements) the index of the element containing a certain value:

e.g let's take the list `a`

```
a = [[0,1,2],[0,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

i want to retrive the indices of the elements containing the value 0, hence my function would return `0,1`

My first try has been the following:

```
def any_identical_value(elements,index):

    for el in elements:

        if el == index:

            return True

    return False


def get_dual_points(compliant_cells, index ):
      compliant = [i for i,e in enumerate(compliant_cells) if any_identical_value(e,index)]
      return compliant


result = get_dual_points(a,0)
```

The solution works correctly but it is highly inefficient for large list of lists. In particular my goal is to perform a number of quesries that is the total number of values in the primary list, hence `n_queries = len(a)*3`, in the example above 9.

Here comes 2 questions:

- Is the list the good data structure to achieve this task?
- Is there a more efficient algorithm solution?

Comment: Are you doing this for only one element, or are you performing several queries for several different values over the list of lists?

Comment: Several queries. The number of queries I have to perform is len(a)*3

Comment: Got it, writing an answer now.

Comment: Algorithms for these kind of problems often come in two steps. Step 1) Preprocess the list of list into a more efficient data structure for this task. Step 2) Process the "query" efficiently using the new data structure. Of course, step 1 can be pretty long, so whether or not such an algorithm would be better than the naive "iterate on the list of lists for every query" depends on how many queries you are expecting.

Comment: *"Several queries. The number of queries I have to perform is len(a)*3 "* Please include this important info in the question post, using the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72002118/edit) button!

Comment: Also, note that `len(a)` is the number of sublists, not the total number of elements.

Comment: you could probably use a technique like binary search assuming your data is sorted, however in the simple case above I wonder if you could probably just do `l[0]` to get the first element and check if it's a 0 for not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hash all indexes in one go (single `O(N)` pass), which would allow you to answer the queries in `O(1)` time.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
a = [[0,1,2],[0,5,6],[7,8,9]]
queries = [0,1]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for element in a[i]:
        d[element].append(i)

for x in queries:
    print(d[x])

# prints
# [0, 1]
# [0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposed algorithm: iterate on the list of lists once, to build a dict that maps **every** unique element to **all** the indices of the sublists it belongs to.

With this method, the dict-building takes time proportional to the total number of elements in the list of lists. Then every query is constant-time.

This requires a dict of lists:

```py
def dict_of_indices(a):
    d = {}
    for i,l in enumerate(a):
        for e in l:
            d.setdefault(e, []).append(i)
    return d

a = [[0,1,2],[0,5,6],[7,8,9]]
d = dict_of_indices(a)
print( d[0] )
# [0, 1]
```

Comment: The answer is correct, but does it offer anything different than the two solutions already provided?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Wow, hold on a second. You submitted your solution pretty much at the exact same time as I did. At least give me a minute to check your solution before you ask me if it's different from mine.

Comment: And @AbhinavMathur's is nearly identical to mine, which I posted before him. We all had the same idea that we all composed at the same time, and I don't think there's anything wrong with that.

Comment: It shows a 3 minute difference. Anyways, that was just a suggestion to _highlight_ whatever difference the answer had

Comment: Actually, I'd be happy to delete my answer. We don't need to show the same solution three times. However I do think using `enumerate` is better in this case than iterating on `range(len(...))`. (1) It's more readable and more pythonic in my opinion; (2) When iterating on dicts, it's faster to iterate on the key,value pairs directly that to iterate on the keys then hash the key at every iteration to get the associated value. I don't know if the same is true when iterating on lists, but it might be.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dictionary that maps from a value to a set of row indices. Then, for each query, you can simply look up the value, returning an empty set if it doesn't exist anywhere in the 2D list:

```py
from itertools import product

a = [[0,1,2],[0,5,6],[7,8,9]]

values = {}

for row, col in product(range(len(a)), range(len(a[0]))):
    value_at_index = a[row][col]
    values.setdefault(value_at_index, set()).add(row)
    
print(values.get(0, set()))
```

This outputs:

```py
{0, 1}
```

---

If you know in advance that the elements within each sublist are unique, then you can change the dictionary update line to:

```py
values.setdefault(value_at_index, []).append(row)
```

and change the `.get()` call to:

```py
values.get(0, [])
```

to maintain the ordering of the indices in the output.

Comment: Note that `for row, col in product(range(len(a)), range(len(a[0]))):` will only work under the assumption that all sublists have the same length.

Comment: You're right; in that case, you'd want to use nested `for` loop where it'd be something like `for row in range(len(a): for col in range(len(a[row])`. Each sublist contains three elements, so this isn't a concern for this question IMO.

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark so why are you adding an import based on an assumption when you can easily work your way around it?

Comment: Because 1.) The question said that such an assumption is valid, and 2.) the purpose of `itertools` is to provide cleaner syntax for situations like these. Yes, you're right I could do without it, but it's not an overly heavy dependency like `numpy` or `pandas`.